# how can i display all image from public path

Tags: laravel

can anyone show me sample of display all image from my public folder

```
     <img src="<?php echo asset('images').'/'.$p->image1 ?>" class="oldimage">
```

that is only one image display by image name. I want to display all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller:

```
$images = File::allFiles(public_path('images'));
```

In view:

```
@foreach ($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}">
@endforeach
```